# if-else not working within class component in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, babeljs

I am trying to produce a set of numbers as `<ul></ul>` elements depending on the number entered in a textbox. However the if-else statement within the event handling function does not work. I tried executing the statement separately and send the boolean value to the if statement but that didn't work as well.

here's the react code:

```
let decide = () => (Number(x) <= 10);

class Message extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
    this.state = {elt: arr.map((number) =>
                              <li key={number.toString()}>
                                 {number}
                              </li>   
                              )}  ;
    this.onSet = this.onSet.bind(this);
  }
  
  onSet(e){ 
      if(decide(e.target.value)) {
        arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];     
      }
      else
      {
        arr = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90];
      }
      
      console.log(Number(e.target.value) <= 10);
      this.setState(
       {elt: arr.map((number) =>
        <li key={number.toString()}>
          {number}
        </li>   
      )}
    );
  }

 render(){
   return (
      <div>
       <input type="text" onKeyUp={this.onSet}></input>
       <ul>{this.state.elt}</ul>
      </div>
    );
 }
    
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Message />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

HTML -

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the function you are using doesn't accept the 'x' parameter.

```
let decide = () => (Number(x) <= 10);
```

Try updating it so that it accepts your passed e.target.value:

```
let decide = (x) => (Number(x) <= 10);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have declared two separate `arr` variables in both if and else block. Define an `arr` variable before if-else blocks just like code below.

```
...

 onSet(e){ 
      let arr=[];  // <== Declare an arr variable outside of if-else block

      if(decide(e.target.value)) {
        arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];     
      }
      else
      {
        arr = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90];
      }

...
```